# Returning parent of more than one panel

Tags: java, swing

I have two JPanels like following.

```
JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
```

and I add these panels to a menu panel in *getContent* method. Menu panel is a child of JPanel.

```
menu.addPanel(panel1);
menu.addPanel(panel2);

return menu;
```

Then this menu panel is added to a container.

```
container.add(getContent());
```

After all, panels are not resized according to container width and height. If I have one JPanel, returning *panel1.getParent()* works. How can I return parent of more than one panel or anything else helps to resize panels?

**Example**

```
public Container getContent() {

    JPanel panel1 = service.getAPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = service.getBPanel();

    Menu menu = new Menu();
    menu.addPanel(panel1);
    menu.addPanel(panel2);

    return menu;
}

public void createPanel() {

    container.add(getContent());
}
```

When I do this, panels (panel1, panel2) do not resize according to the container.

But if I have only one panel, following code block works correctly.

```
public Container getContent() {

    JPanel panel1 = service.getAPanel();

    Menu menu = new Menu();
    menu.addPanel(panel1);

    return panel1.getParent();
}

public void createPanel() {

    container.add(getContent());
}
```

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at the different LayoutManagers instead of trying to manually resize the contents. And what do you mean by "returning"?

Comment: Returning panel1.getParent() in getContent() function instead of return menu. I don't want to manually resize the panels. They should be resized according to container.

Comment: Then i don't understand your question at all.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: *"**Example**"* Maybe it is, but it's not the more specialized MCVE or SSCCE we actually need in order to help. Please add one of those.